# Encoding url for facebook graph like count call

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm trying to make a simple call to facebooks graph API using an fql query.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=' + encodeURIComponent('select total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count from link_stat where url=' + 'http://www.google.se'),
    success: s,
    error: e
});
```

Error: `Parser error: unexpected ':' at position 97.`

Can someone explain how I should encode the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me on Chrome's web developer console:

```
> encodeURIComponent('select total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count from link_stat where url=' + 'http://www.google.se')
> "select%20total_count%2Clike_count%2Ccomment_count%2Cshare_count%2Cclick_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.se"
```

Sounds like it might not be `encodeURIComponent` that failed to encode, but rather a syntax parsing error in your code itself.  Mind posting the code around line 97 and what exactly is on line 97 of your code?

Comment: Noticed that i missed the quotationmarks which should be wrapping the url in the call. Thanks though!